# In J2ME, is there any method or property which similar to the functionality of gotFocus & lostFocus on control

Tags: java-me, lcdui

In my J2ME app, I want to add a play command when got focus on choicegroup control named as `Tones` and after lost focus on choicegroup control the command should be removed.

How should I do this?

**Update:**

Here is my code:

```
 import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

 import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

 public class Focusoncontrol extends MIDlet implements CommandListener
 {  
    Display disp;

    TextField Text1, Text2, Text3;
    ChoiceGroup Tones;
    Form frm;
    Command Save, Back, Play;

    public Focusoncontrol()
    {
        disp = Display.getDisplay(this);
        frm  = new Form("Focus demo");
        Text1 = new TextField("Text1", "", 20, 0);
        Text2 = new TextField("Text2", "", 20, 0);
        Text3 = new TextField("Text3", "", 20, 0);
        Tones = new ChoiceGroup("Tones", Choice.POPUP, new String[]{"Tone 1", "Tone 2"}, null);
        Save = new Command("Save", Command.SCREEN, 1);
        Back = new Command("Back", Command.EXIT, 3);
        Play = new Command("Play", Command.OK, 2);

        frm.append(Text1);
        frm.append(Text2);
        frm.append(Tones);
        frm.append(Text3);
        frm.addCommand(Save);
        frm.addCommand(Back);
        frm.setCommandListener(this);

        disp.setCurrent(frm);
    }

    public void startApp() 
    {
    }

    public void pauseApp() 
    {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) 
    {
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) 
    {
        if(c == Back)
        {
            destroyApp(true);
            notifyDestroyed();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not added Play command during initialization of app because I have to add play command on form when Tones(ChoiceGroup control) got focus and removed the command when ChoiceGroup control lost the focus.

Comment: Can you post some of your code, that shows your choice group control, the container it's in, and maybe how you implement the play command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ChoiceGroup` is an `Item` object, and to use commands like you describe you need  **[ItemCommandListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/ItemCommandListener.html)**:

> A listener type for receiving notification of commands that have been invoked on [Item](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Item.html) objects. An Item can have `Commands` associated with it. When such a command is invoked, the application is notified by having the [commandAction()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/ItemCommandListener.html#commandAction%28javax.microedition.lcdui.Command,%20javax.microedition.lcdui.Item%29) method called on the `ItemCommandListener` that had been set on the Item with a call to [setItemCommandListener()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Item.html#setItemCommandListener%28javax.microedition.lcdui.ItemCommandListener%29)...

To set "play" command for the choicegroup, use method `Item.addCommand(Command)`:

```
Tones.addCommand(Play); // add command to item
Tones.setItemCommandListener(/*... define  item cmd listener*/); // set listener
```

Above code could be written eg right before invoking `disp.setCurrent(frm)` in your code snippet.

Comment: @Rahul it **should** work - if done right: command should appear when `Tones` gets focus and go away when it loses focus. What exactly did not work to you?

Comment: @ gnat Hey gnat.. your trick worked.. Thank you for such nice suggestion and sorry for my previous comment... I deleted that comment.. I hope you will not feel bad...

Comment: @Rahul glad that this helped. One more advice - consider moving initialization code from `Focusoncontrol` constructor into `startApp` method - for the reasons explained in [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14050767/839601)